# autoconf AS_IF doesn't execute correct branch

Tags: configure, autoconf, automake, conditional-compilation

I'm having a bit of a mystery in a autoconf script, specifically `AS_IF`.

Here's the relevant code:

```
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([eventfd], [AC_DEFINE([NN_HAVE_EVENTFD])])
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([pipe], [AC_DEFINE([NN_HAVE_PIPE])])
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([pipe2], [
    AC_DEFINE([NN_HAVE_PIPE2])
    CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -D_GNU_SOURCE"
])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([socketpair], [], [AC_DEFINE([NN_HAVE_SOCKETPAIR])])
```

i.e. checking for their existance. These work correctly and define the correct symbols. In this case, only `NN_HAVE_PIPE` and `NN_HAVE_SOCKETPAIR` gets defined, which is correct as this is a HP-UX system.

Now to the mystery part.
Later in the configure.ac, there's a conditional referring to these symbols:

```
echo "ac_cv_func_eventfd: $ac_cv_func_eventfd"
AS_IF([test x"$ac_cv_func_eventfd"=xyes], [
    AC_DEFINE([NN_USE_EVENTFD])], [
    AS_IF([test x"$ac_cv_func_pipe"=xyes], [
        AC_DEFINE([NN_USE_PIPE])], [
        AS_IF([test x"$ac_cv_func_socketpair"=xyes], [
            AC_DEFINE([NN_USE_SOCKETPAIR])], [
            AC_MSG_ERROR([No signaling supported])
        ])
    ])
])
```

Even though `ac_cv_func_eventfd` has value `no` (I added the echo line to make sure), `NN_USE_EVENTFD` gets defined anyway!

As the `AS_IF` macro is defined as such:

```
AS_IF (test1, [run-if-true1], ..., [run-if-false])
```

To me, the code seems quite correct, no?
Is there anyone that can shed some light on this behavior?

Autoconf version is 2.67. The OS is HP-UX 11.31 ia64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite correct.  You must fix your `AS_IF` test from:

```
test x"$ac_cv_func_eventfd"=xyes
```

to

```
 test x"$ac_cv_func_eventfd" = xyes
```

Note the insertion of spaces around the `=`.  Same goes for the other tests in the other `AS_IF`s.

To verify this you can try seeing this at the command line:

```
if test x"no"=xyes; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
```

vs.

```
if test x"no" = xyes; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
```

Comment: hm... yes, now that you mention it, that is always the case in shell scripting... Didn't think of that :(

Comment: All `AS_IF` does is wrap up shell script code for portability.  The same could be said of much of the rest of autoconf (M4sh, M4sugar, .m4 macros).  `configure` is just a big shell script.